# Matrix formatting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm learning MATLAB right now, and I'm trying to print a matrix that would print both the row and the column. like this:

```
(1,1) (2,1) (3,1)

(1,2) (2,2) (3,2)

(1,3) (3,2) (3,3)
```

But what I am printing is:

```
1,1

2,1

3,1


1,2

2,2

3,2


1,3 

2,3

3,3
```

How can I format a matrix in Matlab?

Comment: see `fprintf` function, maybe it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `fprintf` function to format data e.g.

```
fprintf('\n(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)\n(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)\n(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)\n')
```

Output will be

```
(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)
```

You can try it as below:

```
mat = ones(10);
[r,c] = size(mat);
ind_str = '';
for ii = 1 : r
    for jj = 1 : c
        tmp = sprintf('(%2d,%2d) ',ii,jj);
        ind_str = strcat(ind_str,tmp);
    end
    ind_str = strcat(ind_str,'\n');
end
fprintf(ind_str);
```

Comment: You're not using any of the functionality of `fprintf` there, you can replace that with `disp` and see the same output.

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much for your response. I already tried that earlier and direct printing might work but my issue is that I am creating this matrix by using for loops. Like once I get my problem figured I need to create a 10x10 or even 100x100 matrix of similar nature. This is how my loop is constructed k=1;
for i=1:5
   for j=1:5
       fprintf('%d,%d  \n',j,k)
   end 
   
fprintf(' \n')
k=k+1;
end